# Community users not able to see tile menu images

Tags: lightning-community

I have uploaded images for tile menu directly from my computer under `Edit Default Navigation` in community builder.

These images are visible when logged in as sys admin but not visible to community users.

I am logging with community users directly from contact page using below option. Am I missing any permission here
[image]

Comment: If you check your browsers debugging tools, you should have an error code which indicates why the images are not displayed

Comment: I tried this but didn't see any error code/message. Could there be any object permissions or community setting that I might be missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I removed all images and then uploaded those again. It worked this time!